# Pervent overlapping of Two paired TextView in a row with multiline TextView in RelativeLayout programmatically?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I manage to achieve this by adding to_end_of of a relative layout, but long texts also seems to have problem
[image]

here's the code for doing that:

```
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams keyParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        keyParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_END);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams valueParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        valueParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_START);



        for (Map.Entry<String, String> item : model.getCompanyProperties().entrySet()) {
            RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
            TextView keyText = new TextView(this);
            keyText.setLayoutParams(keyParams);
            keyText.setText(item.getKey());
            keyText.setSingleLine(false);


            TextView valueText = new TextView(this);
            valueText.setGravity(Gravity.START);
            valueText.setTextSize(18);
            valueText.setText(item.getValue());
            valueParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.START_OF, keyText.getId());
            keyParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.END_OF, valueText.getId());
            valueText.setLayoutParams(valueParams);


            layout.addView(keyText);
            layout.addView(valueText);
            repoPropertiesLayout.addView(layout,
                    new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        }

    }
```

Comment: I would get rid of your START_OF rule for valueParams, and make sure you setLayoutParams for keyText after you add its END_OF rule. If you don't get rid of one of them I believe you'll have a circular dependency.

Comment: @ootinii thanks for your answer, but it didn't change anything, I want textViews to beak into lines when there is no room, but this are just Truncating

Comment: like multiple lines?

Comment: @ootinii yeah, I want keyText to be like that, but stays in front

Comment: add android:maxLines and give it a number that isn't 1

Comment: @ootinii it won't change anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I managed to overcome the situation with setting weight to both view and creating `LinearLayout` instead, here's the code:

```
 LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
 layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
 layout.setGravity(Gravity.END);
 TextView valueText = new TextView(this);
 valueText.setText(item.getValue());
 layout.addView(valueText);
 TextView keyText = new TextView(this);
 keyText.setText(item.getKey());
 LinearLayout.LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                0,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                1.0f
        );
 valueText.setLayoutParams(param);
 keyText.setLayoutParams(param);
 layout.addView(keyText);
```